# Avoid subreports in SQL Server Reporting Services by combining datasets to enhance performance

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a free form report which is basically a company overview report.

The report looks something like this:

```
------------
Company XYZ
------------
 - address
 - telephone
-...

**Contacts** 

 - Bryan
 - Caroline
 - Patrick

**Complaints**

 - Complaint 1
 - Complaint 2
```

This report needs to be able to run for multiple company records at once, resulting in a nice print-out per company. I've currently solved this using a main report in which I have the main company selection by using:

```
select companyid from Company
```

This main reports has one table with a subreport in it. I provide the companyid as a parameter to the subreport.

In the subreport I then define the different datasets I need (e.g. Contacts, Complaints, ...) as follows.

- Contacts: `select contactid, name from Contact where companyid = @companyid`
- Orders: `select revenue from order where companyid = @companyid`
- ...

Keep in mind that these datasets are not related to eachother, they are only related to the company

However when running this report for multiple companies, this results in a horrible performance (I have 7 datasets in the subreport, and if the main report is ran for 50 accounts this results in (7+1)* 50 queries.

My question is: is it possible to eliminate the need for a subreport? I tried creating a dataset that is basically a combination of the datasets using unions and adding each dataset as a new set of columns to the main query. However I seem to be stuck on rendering this properly using lists with nested tables.

Are cached datasets a possible solution? If so, how exactly, as I can't seem to figure this out...

Many thanks!